# Windowsアプリケーションが異常終了した場合のリソース開放について

Tags: windows, メモリ管理

例えば、アプリで動的にメモリを確保を行い、解放せず異常終了した場合、
WindowsOSはフェールセーフでメモリ開放してくれる仕組みなどがあるのでしょうか
ない場合は、OS再起動が必要になるのでしょうか。

Answer (score 4, accepted):

メモリを含むほとんどのリソースはプロセス単位で管理されており、プロセスの終了方法に依らず、それらリソースは自動的に解放されます。

例外的に、Mutexなどプロセスを跨いで使われるリソースは明示的に解放する必要があります。

これら挙動はWindowsに限らず、現代のOSの基本的な機能ですので、他のOSでも同じことが言えます。

Comment: 納得いたしました。